# How to disable tomcat undeploy my application?

Tags: tomcat6

When I modify the web.xml for my tomcat6 application, the console print:
"Undeploying context []"

and seems tomcat reloading my app.

I don't want this "hot reloading", how to disable this behavior？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable this by changing the value to false in server.xml file.
autoDeploy="false"